# When using the Azure Fluent SDK in an Azure Function how can I create an azure object using a Managed Service Identity?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am writing an Azure function which will update an Azure DNS zone. The function has a Managed Service Identity (MSI) attached to it.

I am able to use the non-fluent SDK to read the current records in the DNS zone. However when I try and do the same thing using the fluent libraries I get the following error:

> [07/11/2018 14:36:37] Executed 'Function1' (Failed,Id=8d34472e-956a-4ff3-a1b1-16ea6186934a)
>
> [07/11/2018 14:36:37] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1.Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent: Value cannot be null.
>
> [07/11/2018 14:36:37] Parameter name: MSI_ENDPOINT.

So that I can easily test the difference between the two libraries, I have put together a test function.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;

namespace UpdateDNS
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "{subscription}/{rg_name}/{zone_name}/{lib}")] HttpRequest req,
            string subscription,
            string rg_name,
            string zone_name,
            string lib,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            int count = 0;
            dynamic records;

            // determine the lib to use to get the dns data
            switch (lib)
            {
                case "fluent":

                    AzureCredentialsFactory factory = new AzureCredentialsFactory();
                    MSILoginInformation msi = new MSILoginInformation(MSIResourceType.AppService);
                    AzureCredentials msiCred = factory.FromMSI(msi, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
                    var azureAuth = Azure.Configure().WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders).Authenticate(msiCred);

                    // set the subscription to work with
                    var azure = azureAuth.WithSubscription(subscription);

                    var dnszone = azure.DnsZones.GetByResourceGroup(rg_name, zone_name);

                    records = dnszone.ListRecordSets();

                    break;

                default:

                    // get the token from the managed service identity
                    AzureServiceTokenProvider token_provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                    string token = await token_provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com");

                    TokenCredentials token_creds = new TokenCredentials(token);

                    // create the dns client
                    DnsManagementClient client = new DnsManagementClient(token_creds);
                    client.SubscriptionId = subscription;

                    records = client.RecordSets.ListAllByDnsZone(rg_name, zone_name);

                    break;
            }

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(record.Name);
                count++;
            }

            return new OkObjectResult($"Records: {count}");

        }
    }
}
```

This is an HTTP triggered Azure function and allows the subscription, resource group and DNS zone to be passed in as parameters as well as the library to use.

So in order to test the non-fluent libs I can call the following:

http://localhost:7071/api/ee65837a-8b52-4fed-9820-f2eb0bb11baf/my_rg/my_zone/stable

This will return something like:

```
Records: 3
```

However if I try and run the same query but using the fluent libs I get the error as shown above:

http://localhost:7071/api/ee65837a-8b52-4fed-9820-f2eb0bb11baf/my_rg/my_zone/fluent

Am I missing a parameter that needs to be passed in? I am not sure where the 'MSI_ENDPOINT' would be set and what it should be set to. My feeling is that this should be done for me.

The versions of the libraries that are in use are:

> Microsoft.Azure.Management.DNS 3.0.1
>
> Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent 1.17.0
>
> Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication 1.0.3

I am running this locally within Visual Studio which is logged into an account with the appropriate access to Azure.

Comment: MSI_ENDPOINT is an environment variable set by managed identity in Azure. I suppose it is expecting that to exist. You could use AzureServiceTokenProvider to acquire access tokens instead, it'll fallback to using Visual Studio's Azure Service Authentication for example.

Comment: @juunas The MSI is attached to the web site. I have just found that it is an environment variable, but I can only see it when using the Kudu console.

Comment: Did you check Kudu? You can go to yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net and see all available environment variables there. If it isn't there but you have Managed Service Identity turned on, then there is something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, was updating my comment when you replied. Yes I can see it in Kudu.

Comment: In order to get MSI running locally you have to prepare some things with VS. check the instructions here: https://msftplayground.com/2018/08/azure-managed-service-identity-and-local-development/

Comment: @JoeyCai I need to programmatically update the DNS zone when a request comes through on the Azure Function. So that I do not have to pass an SPN around for the function I want to use MSI.

Comment: From the URLs you mentioned in your questions above that seems to be a problem while debugging / running locally. Is that correct? Did the same issue occur while running the function in Azure?

Comment: If you test with MSI in local you only could use the default method you use. Because you could use Azure Service Authentication to retrieve your account. Refer to this [article](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrismann.MicrosoftVisualStudioAsalExtension).

Comment: I am going to deploy the code into Azure and see if it works. I read the article that @SebastianAchatz suggested and thought that I would only need to be logged in using VS. I will provide an update.

Comment: This work around works for me. Basically, you need to authenticate via RestClient with tokens provided by `AzureServiceTokenProvider` and use that `IAuthenticated` to create `IAzure`  https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/585

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am running this locally within Visual Studio which is logged into an account with the appropriate access to Azure.

You don't have Manage Service Identity on your local machine so you could not work well with the first method in local.
As junnas said, you could use `Azure Services Authentication Extension` with `AzureServiceTokenProvider` which retrieves your account to access to Azure.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrismann.MicrosoftVisualStudioAsalExtension).

So, firstly you need to do is go to you `yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net` and select `Environment` to check if there is `MSI_ENDPOINT` variable in it. Which means you have set up MSI successfully.

Secondly, publish the function to Azure and it will work fine.

Comment: In my Visual Studio I do have the `Azure Services Authentication Extension` installed and set to the correct identity.
I am now trying a deployment to Azure to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have now got this working, although not in the way I wanted.
I was trying to do this using CSX but it would not work, however by doing it as a C# project in VS Code and then publishing to Azure it all works.
Thankls for pointers.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: article link is blocked